# Angular and Firebase: unable to ng add @angular/fire

Tags: angular, angularjs, typescript, firebase

It's like three days I'm trying to get this thing done with little results.
I want to use Google Firebase services inside of my Angular project. I'm following [this](https://developers.google.com/codelabs/building-a-web-app-with-angular-and-firebase?hl=it#0) link to use it in my project.
I created a project on firebase and inside of it created a Firestore Database. Then I installed the firebase CLI with

```
sudo npm install -g firebase-tools
```

Then I logged myself in with

```
firebase login
```

and so far everything worked correctly.
But then when I try to install the firebase SDK in my project via

```
ng add @angular/fire
```

the terminal asks me to select which user I want to authorize for using it, I select my email from the list (by the way it's the only one available) and then it exits the operation because "Already using account ***@gmail.com for this project directory".

Then I try to logout from firebase with

```
firebase logout
```

and I do again ng add @angular/fire, but now it asks me for an authorization code. Now I don't know what code is this. I tried to generate an OAuth code from my console in Google Cloud but it doesn't work.

But if I do

```
ng version
```

I get this:

```
     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/
    

Angular CLI: 16.1.8
Node: 20.11.1 (Unsupported)
Package Manager: npm 10.2.4
OS: darwin arm64

Angular: 16.2.12
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1602.12
@angular-devkit/build-angular   16.2.12
@angular-devkit/core            16.2.12
@angular-devkit/schematics      16.1.8
@angular/cli                    16.1.8
@angular/fire                   16.0.0
@schematics/angular             16.1.8
rxjs                            7.8.1
typescript                      5.1.6
zone.js                         0.13.3
```

So looks like @angular/fire got installed, but then if I just try to import a module like

```
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire'
```

I just get an error saying that the @angular/fire module doesn't contains this exported member.
Any thoughts?